# Installing java 1.7 runtime jre-7u4 in silent mode (with no user interaction)

Tags: java, installation

I would like to install jre-7u4-windows-i586.exe and jre-7u4-windows-x64.exe in "silent" mode (without any screens or prompts appearing).

With java 1.6, the command switches were
jre-6u21-windows-x64.exe  /passive "/qb ADDLOCAL=ALL"
which did a completely silent install ok.

With java 1.7,
jre-7u4-windows-x64.exe  /passive "/qb ADDLOCAL=ALL"
  does not work
jre-7u4-windows-x64.exe  /q   (or /qn)
  does not work

The installer runs, but prompts for confirmations.

Does anyone know if this feature is broken?  (by mistake or on purpose?)  Or if there are other switches to use with 1.7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I know in JRE7 /s means silent install mode, so you should try this:
jre-6u21-windows-x64.exe /s INSTALLDIR=DRIVE:\FOLDER...

Comment: That worked, woohoo, thanks!  The `INSTALLDIR=xxx` part is optional, it works with just `/s`.  If you have a web link where you got this info, please post it, in case others want to use additional options.

Comment: The link is from the oracle site http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jre-installer-options.html. But all other options after /s (silent) don't work as stated in their docs. So basically if you want to install silent in a non-default dir your out of luck.